# Why do offsets error out when the height is under 36?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

This is only seemingly happening in Excel 2010.

When I do an namedrange = offset-match-count, I get a column returned. Great. I can do sums, etc. on the column no problem. However, when I try to test if there's a problem, via iserror(Namedrange), I get that there's an error whenever my column is less than 37. So at a column height of 37 or greater, no issue, it works just fine. At a column height of 36 or less, i get an error message when I shouldn't.

It's worth noting that everything sums properly regardless of height. It just fails in this specific instance. There are quite a few workaround I can use - different test, adding 37 to all of my columns, etc. I'm curious why this is happening.

I was unable to replicate the results in Excel 2016.

Comment: Can you give us your formula to check it?

Comment: =not(iserror(FOBSumColumn0)) - it's working for 12 of them, the last 3 aren't working. They're grouped together in sets of 3. Researching why it isn't working lead to the conclusion above